# SVG PATH : LineTo path commands Multiple parameters

Tags: svg, path, command

I got a svg file in which i don't understand how works the multiple parameters given for specifics 'm' and 'v' commands into the 'd' sections for path.

`<path d="m-5.1576 3.5189v0.022851h-0.022-0.022v-0.022851-0.021149h0.022 0.022v0.021149m0-1.2951h-0.022-0.022v-0.021149-0.022851h0.022 0.022v0.022851 0.021149m0.019-0.063h-0.0315-0.0315v0.7 0.7h0.0315 0.0315v-0.0096503-0.0093497h-0.0315-0.0315v-0.681-0.681h0.0315 0.0315v-0.0093497-0.0096503m-0.063 0v0.7 0.7-0.0096503-0.0093497-0.681-0.681-0.0093497-0.0096503m-0.187 1e-15 0.187-1e-15v0.016431 0.015569h-0.0935-0.0935v-0.015569-0.016431m0 1.3836v-0.015569h0.0935 0.0935v0.015569 0.016431h-0.0935-0.0935v-0.016431m0.215-1.3206h-6e-3 -6e-3v0.637 0.637h6e-3 6e-3v-0.637-0.637" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".005"/>`

- `m-0.187 1e-15 0.187-1e-15` got 4 parameters whereas 2 are expected: how can i operate ?
- `h-0.022-0.022` got 2 parameters whereas 1 is expected (should I add the 2 parameters?)
- `v0.7 0.7-0.0096503-0.0093497-0.681-0.681-0.0093497-0.0096503`: same thing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html)

Additional Move values are interpreted as L (or l) commands

Additional values for other commands are treated as another instance of that command. So in your case additional h or v commands.

Comment: thanks and to be sure :<br>
- `m-0.187 1e-15 0.187-1e-15` means `m -0.187 1e-15 l 0.187-1e-15` ?<br>

- `h-0.022-0.022` means `h -0.022 h -0.022` ? <br>